# Why is there no git commit -A -m? It must have been deliberately omitted, but why?

Tags: git, stage

So I can combine `git add -a` and `git commit -m "Add whatever"` using `git commit -a -m "Add whatever"`, but this will only stage tracked files. Why doesn't git offer `git commit -A -m "Add whatever"` so that I can also stage untracked files. It seems like an obvious shortcut so I'm wondering why it has been omitted.

Answer (score 2):

Feel free to suggest it on the git mailing list, or even better send in a patch. Note though that many Git people discourage the use of `-a` for add and commit as you completely lose control over what you actually add.

That being said, you could also make an alias that does both:

```
git config --global alias.commitall "!git add -A && git commit -m $0"
```

Then you could just type `git commitall "Add whatever"` and it will add and commit everything.